# Eloquent filter by child relationship

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel application that shows lists of cars `make`, `model`, `year`, `trim`.

When page loads list of `make` is displayed, user then clicks specific `make` and all `model` are displayed, etc.

These are my tables (already created relationships):

make

```
- id
```

model

```
- id
- id_make
```

year

```
- id
- id_model
```

trim

```
- id
- id_year
```

When showing list of `make`, how can i query only `make` with at least one `model` with at least one `year` with at least one `trim`?

Answer (score 2):

this is simple query :

```
Make::query()->whereHas('model',function ($query){
    $query->whereHas('year',function ($query2){
        $query2->whereHas('trim',function ($query3){
            $query3->orderByDesc('id');
        });
    });
})
    ->get();
```

also you can add condition like this

```
Make::query()->whereHas('model', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('year', function ($query2) {
        $query2->whereHas('trim', function ($query3) {
            $query3->orderByDesc('id');
        })
            ->orderByDesc('id');
    })
        ->orderByDesc('id');
})
    ->orderByDesc('id')
    ->get();
```

but it's not good

better to use deep relationship read bellow package document

https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep